# Windows 10 does not switch desktops from left to right

Tags: windows-10, virtual-desktop

I have just upgraded my `Windows` from `7` to `10` and encountered a bug: <kbd>Ctrl+Win+Left</kbd> does switch desktops from right to left but <kbd>Ctrl+Win+Right</kbd>, which is expected to switch from left to right, does nothing. Did anybody else experince the same? Are there any ideas how to fix the bug?

Comment: Works fine on all the Windows 10s I've used.

Comment: I'm guessing this is because you upgraded Windows in place (despite MS making it easy to do this, it's a terrible idea, fraught with problems, and when I worked there they weren't even interested in bugs that only reproed on such systems). Most likely, you have (or at one point had) a Win7 program that captured that particular key chord, and that's blocking it from getting down to the OS.

Comment: I've seen the issue more deeply, I updated Windows 10 from 8.1 update(Home), current version "Version 1703", It seems to happen only in "Home" version of Windows 10, I am experiencing the same issue, and also looking for solution.